# Problem with the differential equation $y''+x^{\alpha }(1+\sin x^{\beta })y=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

You need to solve the equation $y''+x^{\alpha }(1+\sin x^{\beta })y=0$ through the Liouville transform

I know how to solve such equations and I know I need to make a substitution:
$$y = u(x)\exp\left \{ -\frac{1}{\alpha }\int p(x)dx \right \}$$
I got the answer and all is well. But my teacher asked me to make another substitution, namely $y = x^{\alpha }u(x)$, $u(x)$ is a new function. I got an equation. **Question**: *how can it be solved?*
$$x^{\alpha}u'(x) + (2\alpha+1)x^{\alpha-1}u'(x) + (\alpha^2-x^{\alpha}(1+\sin x^{\beta }))u(x) = 0$$

Comment: You have $y''$ or $y'$?

Comment: What is the Liouville transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the $u'$ terms: $$(x^\alpha+(2\alpha+1)x^{\alpha-1})u'(x)+(\alpha^2-x^\alpha(1+\sin(x^\beta))u(x)=0$$Divide by the coefficient of $u'(x)$: $$u'(x)+\frac{\alpha^2-x^\alpha(1+\sin(x^\beta))}{x^\alpha+(2\alpha+1)x^{\alpha-1}}u(x)=0$$This is a differential equation of the form$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$$The integrating factor is $$e^{\int P(x)dx}$$Where $P(x)$ is the coefficient of $u(x)$. So the answer is $$\frac{C}{e^{\int P(x)dx}}$$Good luck on finding $$\int\frac{\alpha^2-x^\alpha(1+\sin(x^\beta))}{x^\alpha+(2\alpha+1)x^{\alpha-1}}dx$$The second part of the integral is $$\left(-\sin\left({\beta}\right)-1\right)\left(\left(2{\alpha}+1\right)\ln\left(\left|x+2{\alpha}+1\right|\right)-x\right)$$So we now have $$\int P(x)dx=\left(\sin\left({\beta}\right)+1\right)\left(\left(2{\alpha}+1\right)\ln\left(\left|x+2{\alpha}+1\right|\right)-x\right)+\int\frac{\alpha^2}{x^\alpha+(2\alpha+1)x^{\alpha-1}}dx$$